# Adding images inside a randomized question in html , js , php

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, variables

I'm trying to make a randomized quiz similar to this one below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Random Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="message001">This country's capital is <text id="name001"></text>.</p>
    <div id="disappear001">
    <input type="text" id="input001" /><button onclick="submit001()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    <p id="answer001"></p>
    <p id="button001"></p>

    <script>
        var capitals001 = ["Jerusalem", "London", "Washington DC", "Addis Ababa"];
        var countries001 = ["Palestine", "UK", "USA", "Ethiopia"];
        var random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * capitals001.length);

        function submit001() {
            var b = input001.value;
            if (random001 == 0 && b == countries001[0]) {
                document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Correct..";
                document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
                document.getElementById("disappear001").innerHTML = "";

            } else if (random001 == 1 && b == countries001[1]) {
                document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Correct..";
                document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
                document.getElementById("disappear001").innerHTML = "";

            } else if (random001 == 2 && b == countries001[2]) {
                document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Correct..";
                document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
                document.getElementById("disappear001").innerHTML = "";

            } else if (random001 == 3 && b == countries001[3]) {
                document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Correct..";
                document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
document.getElementById("disappear001").innerHTML = "";
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Incorrect..";
                document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
                document.getElementById("disappear001").innerHTML = "";
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("name001").innerHTML = capitals001[random001];

        function btn001() {
            random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * capitals001.length);
            document.getElementById("name001").innerHTML = capitals001[random001];
            document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("disappear001").innerHTML = "<input type=text id=input001 /><button onclick=submit001()>Submit</button>";
            document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to change the questions part:

```
var capitals001 = ["Jerusalem", "London", "Washington DC", "Addis Ababa"];
```

into an array of images.  Rather than randomizing the questions with those, I want to make a randomized question which picks a random picture.  How do I do that?  Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks x)

Comment: Just put image tags into the array using encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of url to your images and then create an 'img' element and bind its src to your array:

```
    var capitals001 = ["Jerusalem", "London", "Washington DC", "Addis Ababa"];
    var capitalsImg001 = ["path/to/image.jpg", "path/to/image2.jpg", "path/to/image3.jpg", "path/to/image4.jpg"];
    var countries001 = ["Palestine", "UK", "USA", "Ethiopia"];
    var random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * capitals001.length);

...

 function btn001() {
            random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * capitals001.length);
            document.getElementById("name001").innerHTML = "<img src="+capitalsImg001[random001]+" />";
            document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("disappear001").innerHTML = "<input type=text id=input001 /><button onclick=submit001()>Submit</button>";
            document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "";
        }
```

Comment: so i tried this, but it didnt seem to work..it doesnt display anything... should i also put something into the body like <p id="message001">This country's capital is <text id="name001"></text><img src = "" id =""></img></p>, if so, what should i input in the src and id?

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURIComponent and decodeURIComponent to send mixed content.

```
 var questions = [];
 questions.push(encodeURIComponent("what is the capital of spain? <img src='/path_to_image.png' />"));
```

Then when you display it:

```
 document.getElementById("question").innerrHTML = decodeURIComponent(questions[0]);
```